# CSS conditional selector based on next element class

Tags: html, css, conditional-statements, css-grid

I have a div type `.cell.title` . It would be very helpful if I could change its `grid-column` value, based on whether or not the next element is `.cell.kicker`, or `.cell.body`.

I could do this using js, but I'm curious to know if css has some kind of forward-looking way of affecting styling, along the lines of this purely imaginary notation:

```
.cell.title {
    grid-column: auto;
}

.cell.title=>.cell.body {
    grid-column: 1/-1;
}
```

I have my doubts this exists, but it's also hard to search for. Lots of things about siblings, but not conditional on what follows, as opposed to what precedes the tagged element.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a "previous sibling" selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector)

Comment: In the sense that there isn't one.

Comment: Looks like you will have to do it with JS. If you have JQuery, you can JQuery.prev